# How to add orders array in product

Tags: node.js

Whenever a customer checks out its saves an order that has products ordered by a customer and the product id, quantity and customers details like delivery address and customer phone number.

I want the same details to be added to all products in that order also so that the seller can also see that his product has been ordered
This i can achieve using each product's id in the orders since every product has its ID . But i dont know how to map the order's products id's and find the products in the products schema then add to them an array called orders.

This is how my orders schema looks like after an order has been placed

```
{
    "allOrders": [
        {
            "_id": "6249ee9baa59aceb7d88f91d",
            "placedby": "624471321dff6794a802431c",
            "fullname": "Collins Jimu",
            "deliveryaddress": "cnr fourth and herbet chitepo",
            "phonenumber": "0773468496",
            "whatsappphonenumber": "0773468496",
            "ordersList": [
                {
                    "name": "Hp 200 G4Core I5",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 560,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648734312/cwynmzauqqnylrwsgejy.jpg",
                    "id": "6245b0c09390975e16263136"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bed",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 160,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648732217/dtrb8saj0ellgyrcjpyy.jpg",
                    "id": "6245a88cf22df558d8d69162"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Sunglass",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 6,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648738341/rtpiptqc1le6kywmuisf.jpg",
                    "id": "6245c03bf22df558d8d6a739"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sofas",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 890,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648732837/xae655b5e9wovodfkvqn.jpg",
                    "id": "6245aacdf22df558d8d6939f"
                }
            ],
            "paymentmethod": "cashondeliver",
            "orderstatus": "placed",
            "createdAt": "2022-04-03T18:59:39.681Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-04-03T18:59:39.681Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6249fdc602cefac4faa36dde",
            "placedby": "624471321dff6794a802431c",
            "fullname": "My MUM",
            "deliveryaddress": "123 HARARE STREET",
            "phonenumber": "0773550804",
            "whatsappphonenumber": "0773550804",
            "ordersList": [
                {
                    "name": "out door benches",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 25,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648736078/in8rumwcm6rrebrmgb1q.jpg",
                    "id": "6245b792be41db13f9220867"
                },
                {
                    "name": "hammer",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 10,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648735570/joceetdkx4penomtab8s.jpg",
                    "id": "6245b5849390975e16263647"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Watches",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 4,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648735962/r4jmwlj7ltgc0njdtfdc.jpg",
                    "id": "6245b71abe41db13f92207ac"
                },
                {
                    "name": "iPhone X",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 350,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648729600/ekcb86lmtkr0uniirb2i.jpg",
                    "id": "62459fc3be41db13f921f27a"
                },
                {
                    "name": "REFRIDGERATOR",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 370,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648731962/fjrlvfnotdbonqnt9pjn.jpg",
                    "id": "6245a750be41db13f921f796"
                }
            ],
            "paymentmethod": "cashondeliver",
            "orderstatus": "placed",
            "createdAt": "2022-04-03T20:04:22.349Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-04-03T20:04:22.349Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "624a12ea02cefac4faa431fd",
            "placedby": "624471321dff6794a802431c",
            "fullname": "Munyaradzi Makosa",
            "deliveryaddress": "cnr fourth and herbet",
            "phonenumber": "0777727363663",
            "whatsappphonenumber": "0777727363663",
            "ordersList": [
                {
                    "name": "Wheels",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 35,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648741496/xs9zpht0rhxpijrzyqrz.jpg",
                    "id": "6245cc859390975e162657ce"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MacBook Pro 2021",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 1250,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648731661/h0dcvvhwntdy06mzgpah.webp",
                    "id": "6245a6649390975e16262737"
                },
                {
                    "name": "electric kettle",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 22,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648734446/tyrdlrayn3opm7gagwmi.jpg",
                    "id": "6245b1239390975e162631e3"
                }
            ],
            "paymentmethod": "cashondeliver",
            "orderstatus": "placed",
            "createdAt": "2022-04-03T21:34:34.721Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-04-03T21:34:34.721Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "624aa7cd02cefac4faa4750c",
            "placedby": "624aa7a102cefac4faa474f3",
            "fullname": "Ryan Katayi",
            "deliveryaddress": "4164 Gwabalanda",
            "phonenumber": "0718518438",
            "whatsappphonenumber": "0718518438",
            "ordersList": [
                {
                    "name": "Budi 2017",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 250,
                    "imgUrl": "/assets/images/products/Automotive/2.Audi2017.png",
                    "id": "6270512109915791"
                }
            ],
            "paymentmethod": "cashondeliver",
            "orderstatus": "placed",
            "createdAt": "2022-04-04T08:09:49.618Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-04-04T08:09:49.618Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "624c0e770d2cf94693988609",
            "placedby": "624aa7a102cefac4faa474f3",
            "fullname": "Ryan Katayi",
            "deliveryaddress": "4164 Gwabalanda",
            "phonenumber": "0718518438",
            "whatsappphonenumber": "0778687452",
            "ordersList": [
                {
                    "name": "Nike Airforce",
                    "qty": 2,
                    "price": 40,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1649082553/hoodaley8bzrwa8xi2tr.jpg",
                    "id": "624b01250d2cf94693982652"
                },
                {
                    "name": "iPhone X",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 350,
                    "imgUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kwingy/image/upload/v1648729600/ekcb86lmtkr0uniirb2i.jpg",
                    "id": "62459fc3be41db13f921f27a"
                }
            ],
            "paymentmethod": "cashondeliver",
            "orderstatus": "placed",
            "createdAt": "2022-04-05T09:40:07.719Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-04-05T09:40:07.719Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

i have managed to get the ids of all the orders. But my challenge is i am stuck with only the products ids not sure how to use them and find each products and then patch them with an orders details array

```
const sellerProductsOrdered = asyncHandler (async (req, res) => {
    const Orders = await Order.find();
    const ordersList =  Orders.map(order => {
        return order
    })

    const ordersListProductsIds = ordersList.map(product => {
        return product.id
    })

    console.log(ordersListProductsIds);
})
```

Comment: so - what have you tried - and what isn't it doing?

Comment: const sellerProductsOrdered = asyncHandler (async (req, res) => {
    const Orders = await Order.find();
    const ordersList =  Orders.map(order => {
        return order
    })

    const ordersListProductsIds = ordersList.map(product => {
        return product.id
    })

    console.log(ordersListProductsIds);
})

i have managed to get the ids of all the orders. But my challenge is i am stuck with only the products ids not sure how to use them and find each products and then patch them with an orders details array

Comment: could you rather please paste the code in the original question - that it is nicely formatted?  comments aren't great for code

Comment: i have pasted in the original question .... thank you